# Most important drive characteristics for swapfile/swappartition / pagefile?

Tags: linux, windows, swap

So, this is potentially a two-fold question because I wonder about both how Windows (11) and Linux (6.5) handle their corresponding swapfile/swappartition and pagefile I/O.
What are the most important characteristics of a dedicated swap drive (SSD) on these systems?

I started thinking about this after I started running out of RAM on my ~10 years old home-server and wanted to spend as little on the problem as possible.
Of course, creating a swapfile or a new partition on an existing drive is possible. But my only drive which has partitions at all or a filesystem which supports swapfile is a fairly slow Intel SATAII SSD (well, slow by today's standards, that is).
And then I remembered the Intel Optane M10 drives. Those were marketed for caching with low latency and high random I/O characteristics and also high write endurace.
I found an old benchmark (LinuxTechTips video) where an M10 32Gb was much faster than a SATAIII SSD in a benchmark where they tested a Windows system by severely limiting the available system RAM via msconfig parameters and placed the pagefile.sys on either a SATAIII SSD or an Optane M10 32Gb (the optane-swap was much closer to real [not artificially limited size] RAM than the SATAIII SSD).

Since those M10 drives are fairly old, I figured they must be cheap today. And the 16Gb version is indeed dirt cheap now (the 32Gb not so much, neither the 805p 84Gb -> the price goes up faster than both the size and the speed specifications). Or course, as it is often the case with any type of SSD, bigger=faster (up to a point). Remember, I wished to keep it cheap. Otherwise I could just buy more real RAM which is definitely much faster and more convenient/practical as well (the M.2 slot could be used for something else but the empty memory slots will only accept RAM...). So M10 16Gb it is!

The M10 16Gb was so cheap, I immediately ordered two sticks. One for a swappartiton in the home-server and one for ... well, either to build a cheap but fast "pendrive" using a cheap USB-NVMe case, or put it into my main desktop PC which has plenty of RAM (32Gb and gaming is the most demanding thing I do nowadays) but still has a pagefile (because how strict Windows is with virtual memory allocations compared to Linux, how much memory processes like to allocate beyond what they actually use and how some stupid software exist that doesn't work reliably without a pagefile, even if just giving 100Mb or so is enough for them to be happy...).

But I wonder if an M10 16Gb is actually faster as a pagefile holder than a Samsung 980 Pro (which has an SLC mode NAND cache and a much faster controller, wider 8x, PCI-e bus, etc...). In case swapping might actually happen on the Windows desktop PC, I don't want to make it worse just because I put the pagefile to an old and small Optane drive "for fun".

Did anybody test this recently? Or do I have to test this for myself? (Trying to replicate some of Linus's benchmarks.)

And is the M10 16Gb really better for Linux swap than a much younger SATAIII SSD?
I am not sure how the Windows benchmark translates to Linux.
Do these OSs handle swap I/O differently? I have no idea how to test this...

After I ordered the M10s I remembered I have a spare Kingston A400 128Gb lying around. Although I could probably sell it for twice as much as the M10 16Gb cost (or keep it as a spare drive like I did before...).

I find it a little strange nobody is playing with these drives nowadays when they aren't overpriced anymore. (It's obvious why it wasn't a popular toy at MSRP.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tested an M10 16Gb in my Windows 11 machine (with artificially limited amount of system memory) and the short answer is:
The M10 16Gb is much worse for swapping than the 980 Pro 1Tb.

A Blender benchmark score only showed ~15% penalty but the system's responsiveness during the first phase of the benchmark (asset loading and whatnot) is "pretty much smooth like there was enough RAM" vs. "video playback freezes and sound is distorted".

I also tried to check if the PCH was to blame (the 980 Pro is connected to the CPU SoC while the M10 is connected to the PCH) but it doesn't look like it (simply benchmarking the SSD synthetically doesn't cause video playback disturbance).

Buuut... a 5 USD 13.6GiB swap partition will still be great for the home server where it will be compared to a SATAII SSD. (And that was the original idea.)